# Recycler View color Alternator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want the cardviews in my recycler view to alternate colors in a specific wat. Currently i am only able to color the cards based on whether they fall in an odd or even index, As shown in the first diagram

[image: This is what i have currently]

This is my code

```
 if ((position % 2) == 0) {
            holder.cv.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        } else {
            holder.cv.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
```

So this is my current order as per index
 0 - Orange
 1 - Blue
 2 - Orange
 3 - Blue
 4 - Orange
 5 - Blue

[image: But this is what i wanted to achieve]

This is the order  i want to achieve
 0 - Orange
 1 - Blue
 2 - Blue
 3 - Orange
 4 - Orange
 5 - Blue
How can i achieve this?

Comment: How does the sequence go on? Does it repeat or does it continue alternating 2 colors?
Example:
1) orange, blue, blue, orange orange, blue, orange, blue blue orange orange...
2) orange, blue, blue, orange, orange, blue, blue, orange, orange, blue blue...

Comment: @SamuelePontremoli i need it to alternate the colors such that no row has exact similar color sequence as the previous row. Check the second diagram to see the order am trying to achieve.

Comment: you can save your color details along with your data which you are using to inflate your recyclerview

Comment: Create a model class with name, icon and color. set colors based on your needed, finally send it in your adapter class and set a cardbackground it will work

Answer (score 1):

try this condition my friend

```
boolean temp = false;

if ((i % 2) == 0) {

        viewHolder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorLightBlue));
        if (temp) {
            temp=false;
            viewHolder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
        } else {
            viewHolder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorLightBlue));
            temp = true;
        }

    } else {
        if (!temp) {
            temp=false;
            viewHolder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorLightBlue));
        } else {
            viewHolder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
            temp = true;
        }

    }
```

**OutPut of the Above condition**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you load data:

```
private int i = 0; 
private int colorCount = 2;
private boolean ba = true;
private List<MemberData> MemberDATA= new ArrayList<>();
```

for (Api_Model.member_list dataset : curators.member_list) {

```
                        if (i != 0) {

                            if (colorCount > 0) {
                                ba = false;
                                colorCount--;
                                if (colorCount == 0) {
                                    colorCount = -2;
                                }
                            } else if (colorCount < 0) {
                                ba = true;
                                colorCount++;
                                if (colorCount == 0) {
                                    colorCount = 2;
                                }

                            }
                        } else {
                            i = 10;
                            ba = true;
                        }



                        MemberData mMember = new MemberData(dataset.userID,
                                dataset.name,
                                dataset.image,
                                ba);
                        MemberDATA.add(mMember);


                    }
```

and set this boolean ba in your arraylist model class:
Now in adapter change color based on boolean.

```
    if(ba){
      //set blue color
    }else{
      //set orange color
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it here's a generic enough solution for you. It should work for a RecyclerView.
First off calculate the row you are in and only later think about the color of the item. If you have an odd row then color blue the even column and orange the odd. Viceversa for the odd rows.
To calculate the row number of a position, just divide the position by 2, which is the number of items per row you have.

Comment: I think you didn't read the complete question. He has already implemented even/odd concept for his recyclerview

Comment: Nope, read carefully my answer. He implemented a logic for even/odd columns. position%2 just gives you the column evenness or oddness.
He also has to do somethig like position/2 to know the number of the row, and then determine if it's even or odd (the ROW, again, not the column).

Comment: yeah understood your point now. Also it would be good if you got give a cod snippet for the same